# How is the straight line drawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The wiki [article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Mating_and_population) for 'doors' in a village in refrence to population concerns states that the inside blocks have to be more than the outside blocks, in a straight line 5 blocks long. Is that line parallel to the closed door's facing or perpindecular to it?

[image]

Comment: Nicely hand-drawn.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Hand drawn? I would have guessed random generator.

Comment: @Ben Think "smartphone touch screen."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is perpendicular to the closed door's facing, or in other words, the line is perpendicular to the wall. It goes 5 blocks inwards and 5 blocks outwards.

Comment: how can you be sure? have you tested this?

Comment: @Ender I have not tested this personally, however, I've seen videos demonstrating the exact configuration. Sadly, right now I can't link to any of them. As a bonus argument, if the line was parallel to the closed door's facing, most of the generated village houses wouldn't have valid doors.